# Struggling with js promises, foreach promise add results

Tags: javascript

Could somebody help me with this problem, I'm trying to retrieve how much data has been send with webrtc. But I can't get my head around these promises.

I need to iterate throught he list of senders, but for each sender I need to await the promise before I can continue with the next sender.

```
// Reset datacounter
Client.DataUsed = 0;

// Get senders (audio/video)
const senders = Client.WebcamConnection.getSenders();

// Iterate through senders
senders.forEach(sender => {
    // Get the stats then await the promise using then
    sender.getStats().then(stat => {
        // Iterate through raports of stat
        stat.forEach(report => {
            // Check if is the right raport
            if (report.type === 'outbound-rtp') {
                // Add the byte count to the datacounter
                Client.DataUsed += report.bytesSent + report.headerBytesSent;
            }
        });
    });
});

// Do something with the Client.DataUsed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can't use the results until all the promises are settled. You can use `Promise.all` to wait for them, see `***` comments:

```
// Reset datacounter
Client.DataUsed = 0;

// Get senders (audio/video)
const senders = Client.WebcamConnection.getSenders();

// ***Create an array of promises, one for each sender, and pass it into
// `Promise.all`***
Promise.all(senders.map(sender => {
    // *** Return the promise created by `then` so `Promise.all` can
    // wait for it***
    // Get the stats then await the promise using then
    return sender.getStats().then(stat => {
        // Iterate through raports of stat
        stat.forEach(report => {
            // Check if is the right raport
            if (report.type === 'outbound-rtp') {
                // Add the byte count to the datacounter
                Client.DataUsed += report.bytesSent + report.headerBytesSent;
            }
        });
    });
})
.then(() => {
    // Do something with the Client.DataUsed
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Comment: @ikwillem - My pleasure! FWIW, I go into promises a fair bit in Chapter 8 of my book coming out in a couple of months. If you're interested, see my profile for details. (Huh, I just noticed that it's still listed at the old price [it's meant to go up by $10].)